# How to check if view is schemabound or not in a Redshift database?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have created a view in Redshift with no schema binding but how can I check for other schema bound views in the database?

Previously, I used SQL Server which had the functionality to check whether the view is schema bound or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the view definition to see if that option has been used:

```
SELECT
        c.oid                  ,
        n.nspname AS schemaname,
        c.relname AS viewname  ,
        pg_get_viewdef(c.oid, true) as viewdefinition
FROM
        pg_class c
JOIN
        pg_namespace n
ON
        c.relnamespace = n.oid
WHERE
        c.relkind                      = 'v'::"char"
AND     pg_get_viewdef(c.oid, true) LIKE '%with no schema binding%'
```

Comment: Thank you @Nathan

Comment: lower(pg_get_viewdef(c.oid, true)) NOT LIKE